# Cannot access Azure VM throught rdp but remote powershell works

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, rdp, powershell-remoting

I need your help, any idea is welcome.

[skipable]

Here's the situation : i was working on a VM hosted in Microsoft cloud (Azure), everything was fine. This VM was supposed to be a Domain Controller (Active Directory), which was link to many VMs (i was working on grid computing with many compute nodes). Everything was setup correctly. The next step was to host a WCF service on a IIS server accessible through https. Therefore i opened port 443 on firewall as well as an valid endpoint for the VM (azure portal). From there things get weird. Opening endpoint 443 on the azure portal didn't work as expected, i needed to reboot the VM. Then i cannot access through RDP connection anymore :-(. However i succeed to take control of the VM via powershell remoting.

[Question]

How can i restore rdp connection via powershell remoting ONLY ? I tried to disabled firewall, open port 3389, capture an image of the vm to recreate it etc.. but nothing worked. Any idea ? i don't want to loose all my work, my fresh service etc..

Thanks you!

Comment: i succeed to get the interface of my VM by installing a VNC server remotely via powershell. But i can't figure out why RDP is not accessible :(

Comment: Have you tried this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2014/03/06/enable-rdp-or-reset-password-with-the-vm-agent.aspx

Comment: i tried but nothing. As far as i understand, the VM agent will only re-create rules for firewall (ie : open 3389)